# How can I subscribe to amazon SNS topic with all pods in cluster?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-sns

I have a Kubernetes cluster with 5 replica sets running a Spring Boot server and I would like to subscribe each pod to an amazon sns topic individually. Is it possible? How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a Spring server, you can create an endpoint and mark those endpoints as subscribers to your sns topic. You would need one subscription for each pod (you should be able to get pod address information by running `kubectl describe svc ${service_name}`) in order for sns to properly fanout messages to all of your pods. AWS outlines this process [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html)

**edit:** worth noting the above process is not very robust since that pod address list may not be static. it may be better to subscribe your **service** to the sns topic, since this abstracts the changing pod IP list, and implement pod-to-pod communication, similar to what is outlined in [this article](https://superuser.openstack.org/articles/review-of-pod-to-pod-communications-in-kubernetes/)

Comment: I tried doing this, but I got stuck at the SubscriberRequest, because I have to pass as argument the pod full endpoint URL, but I don't know how to get it to make the subscription.

Comment: added some more info in the post for clarification on how to get pod info, and an edit for another route you could go to avoid the fact that the pod ip list is not necessarily static